# Travel from Netherlands, stay within Schengen - but with an expired Italian passport

Tags: air-travel, schengen, passports, netherlands, freedom-of-movement

Essentially looking for confirmation of my understanding of travel in and out of the Netherlands, to France (or Austria) for a week, for an EU Citizen (Italian) with an **expired** (by 2 months) Italian passport.  Person is my girlfriend.

Born in South Africa, but with Italian citizenship.  Resident in Netherlands for less than 3 months so do not yet have Dutch residents permit.  Was permitted to enter the Netherlands from the UK (where she lived for 9 years), despite only having a few weeks of validity on the passport.

**Europa.eu** search of what is possible on an expired passport, in and out of the Netherlands:

> Whatever your nationality, an expired passport is not accepted as a valid travel document to enter or leave the Netherlands.
>   [europa.eu expired passport](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/expired-lost-passports/netherlands/index_en.htm)

Seems very cut and dried.  Is there some other valid travel document that would be proof?  Only other currently held ID is a UK Driving License, or a South African passport with no Schengen visa, in her married name, She has marriage certificate if the dots need to be joined...

But looking on **IATA** for the possibilities of travel, when all the details are entered, it appears to show that travel IS possible to France - when I fill in the details (i.e. Italian, passport dates, depart from Netherlands, fly to France for a week, resident in Netherlands, Alien Passport as proof), I see that

> Yes, The documentation you hold is sufficient based on your details and the itinerary provided.

Is Europa.eu the safest source of information?  Does the Netherlands have stricter requirements?

Air travel is the preferred option - but train or driving could be done, if that makes any difference.  **Can she leave and re-enter the Netherlands with what she's got?**

Comment: As a non-EU citizen, I recently traveled Amsterdam - Zurich - Malaga (and back) - the only time I used my passport was to scan it at the kiosk to print my boarding passes. It was not requested once; except as a proof of ID at Malaga during boarding on my final leg; but there you could have gotten by with any kind of government ID.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, when you cross borders *within* the Schengen zone you have to carry travel documents and present them during random checks. These random checks are supposed to be very unlikely, so that the *average* traveler is not bothered.

Comment: She has to prove her **identity** and her **citizenship**. Does she have any documents to prove the citizenship?

Comment: @o.m.  Thanks, that's a good way of looking at it.She has an Italian passport, expired.   Her birth certificate is from SA, so that's not of use.   She is attempting to fast track Dutch ID card via her work, but that will likely take longer than she'd like.

Comment: @Gordonjackson, can the Italian embassy help with emergency travel documents? That should go faster than a new "regular" passport.

Comment: Thanks o.m.  Italian embassy in Netherlands might be a possibility.  They were almost impossible to deal with in the UK, but may be better in Netherlands.    I will ask her to check.    By your answer, does that mean that what she currently has is not valid for Netherlands->France->Netherlands?  p.s. she doesn't speak Italian, having been raised in SA which doesn't help! :)

Comment: @Gordonjackson, I cannot give a definite answer on this, so I'm sticking to comments and not an answer. As an EU citizen she is allowed to enter France and the Netherlands, but she is required to carry the documents to prove that she is allowed to do so. *Usually* that is a passport or national ID card.

Comment: @o.m. thank you yes it is an unanswerable question!  Thanks for your pointers - she is phoning the embassy on Friday in Den Haag to see what might be possible.

Comment: An expired passport certainly should go a long way towards establishing citizenship, or at least a strong presumption. Since she also have a valid and current ID, it might be enough.

Answer (score 3):

For later readers...

We travelled from Amsterdam Central, on the train, to St. Anton am Alberg in Austria, via Koln in Germany.

There were no passport checks along the way, and no ID required apart from my girlfriend had to present the credit card she bought the international train tickets with, on the DB (German trains).

Thanks for everyone's input.  Your mileage may vary, and I understand that there can be passport/ID checks along the way, just that we did not experience any.